# Is there any rhyme or reason in how the tags are ordered?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

If I edit a question to add tags, when the question is re-posted, the tags are shuffled from the order in which they had appeared.  Is there some principle that governs the resulting order?  I can't fathom what it might be.  Maybe I'm making too much of this, but it's weird, and sometimes it might be helpful to put the tags in some specific order, such as having the most important tag first.

Comment: Most to least popular? Anecdotally, that once appeared to be the case when I noticed this same thing. I never checked that closely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags sort by popularity: see [this reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74593/166924).

Comment: Huh. Is there any way to coerce the system to order the tags in a particular order? If people search on a tag, the question would still show up, but for human readers, I would prefer to order tags by relevance to the question.

Comment: Please refer to the [related threads on the meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Btag+%2Border+%2B[discussion]).